# Custom calendar in Codename One

Tags: calendar, codenameone

I'm trying to create custom calendar in Codename One to be able to select, add text to different days, etc. based on some datasource. 
Default calendar doesn't have any datasource - probably it is more likely to be Date Picker rather than Calendar with different functionalities.

My first approach was to extend default Calendar and override **updateButtonDayDate** method. It gives some felxibility - I am able to change text or other things. Unfortunately updateButtonDayDate is called in constructor of Calendar so it is impossible to initialize custom calendar before based class Calendar will call its constructor and run updateButtonDayDate in it (bytecode manipulation is not an answer).

My second idea was to just set different **UIID** to days elements during initialization. Unfortunately I don't see any method which allows me to find element by UIID.

Is it any possibility in Codename One Calendar to select days, set days description based on datasource? Or do I have to create my own component which will include all these functionalities?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the original [Calendar](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Calendar.html) class was designed as a date picker more than anything.

You can use `setName()` or just keep a reference to every day component within the subclass so you can modify that reference directly e.g. `Map<Date, Button>`.

Notice that you can just take the code as a starting point and change it to suit your needs, I'm not sure if `Calendar` is a great example of good engineering as it is a REALLY old component that predated Codename One and isn't as widely used so it didn't enjoy the modernization the rest of the code got. Most developers just need a picker and for that the `Picker` component provides a better alternative.